# Why some items aren't clickable in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

```java
        if (type=="dialer") {
            String timestamp = list.get(position).get(Constants.DATE);
            holder.txtTimestamp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.imgDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.txtTimestamp.setText(getDate(Long.parseLong(timestamp),"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));

            if (Integer.parseInt(callType) == CallLog.Calls.BLOCKED_TYPE)
                holder.imgCallType.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.block));
            if (Integer.parseInt(callType) == CallLog.Calls.BLOCKED_TYPE)
                holder.imgCallType.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rejected));
            if (Integer.parseInt(callType) == CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE)
                holder.imgCallType.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.outgoing_call));
            if (Integer.parseInt(callType) == CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE)
                holder.imgCallType.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.incoming_call));
            if (Integer.parseInt(callType) == CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE)
                holder.imgCallType.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.missed_call));
            if (Integer.parseInt(callType) == CallLog.Calls.ANSWERED_EXTERNALLY_TYPE)
                holder.imgCallType.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.call_received));
        }else if (type=="contact") {
            holder.txtTimestamp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.imgCallType.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.imgDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else if (type=="favourite"){
            holder.txtTimestamp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.imgCallType.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

//        listener
        Bitmap finalBitmap = imgBitmap;
        holder.imgPic.setOnLongClickListener(view -> {
            CustomDialog imageDialog = new CustomDialog(activity,R.layout.image_dialog,"","","", finalBitmap);
            imageDialog.setCancelable(true);
            imageDialog.show();
            return false;
        });
        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(view->{
            if (type=="dialer"){

            }else if (type=="contact"){
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ContactDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id",list.get(position).get(Constants.ID));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }else if (type=="favourite"){
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, FavouriteContactDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(Constants.FAVOURITE_ID,list.get(position).get(Constants.FAVOURITE_ID));
                intent.putExtra(Constants.ID,list.get(position).get(Constants.ID));
                ActivityOptions anim = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity);
                context.startActivity(intent, anim.toBundle());
            }
            return false;
        });

        holder.imgDelete.setOnClickListener(v->{
            SqliteFavourite sqliteFavourite = new SqliteFavourite(context.getApplicationContext());
            boolean check = sqliteFavourite.deleteData("",list.get(position).get(Constants.ID));
            if (check)
                Snackbar.make(v,"Successfully deleted",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else Snackbar.make(v,"Error occurred when deleting",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view->{
              call(activity,phoneNumber);
        });
```

I was using these code in an adapter.

```java
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txtContactName,txtContactNumber,txtTimestamp;
        ImageView imgPic,imgCallType,imgDelete;
        ConstraintLayout contactItem;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtContactName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            txtContactNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtContactNumber);
            txtTimestamp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTimestamp);
            imgPic = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgContact);
            imgCallType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgCallType);
            contactItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contactItem);
            imgDelete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgDeleteContact);
        }
    }
```

Whenever I am clicking on first or second item then I can hear the clickListener. But when I click on 3rd 4th or higher item then I can't hear the clickListener. Even I had set a selector there but the selector is only working for 1st and 2nd

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/contactItem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:clickable="true">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgContact"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/user_profile"
                app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
                app:civ_border_width="2dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtName"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txtContactNumber"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imgCallType"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgContact"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtContactNumber"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Contact Number"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/txtTimestamp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imgCallType"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgContact"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtName" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTimestamp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/txtContactNumber"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgContact"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txtContactNumber" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgCallType"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/call_received"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgDeleteContact"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/selector"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I scroll down then I can hear the listener but whenever I am on top at that layout then I can't access the listener in 3rd or more. Why it's happening? I am not getting any error in logcat. Although I can't click on some items why? I had tried to use `holder.contactItem.setOn....`  but it wasn't working also.

---

When I scroll down I can listen the click. But whenever I am at top I can't listen. But I wonder I can click on Image. I meant `holder.imgPic.setOnLongClickListener.....`.

---

I have set `onTouchListener` to `itemView` but it's working. It's only not working for onCLickListener and onLongClickListener (As I said earlier it's working when I scroll down).

---

I have tried

```xml
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:longClickable="false"
```

although I was facing the same issue. I had used them in Constraint Layout which I declared as `contactItem`. Then I had tried `holder.contactItem` instead of `holder.itemView`

Comment: One mistake you are making is using `==` to compare strings, like `type == "dialer"`. That does not do what you think it does in Java. See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: You are doing things like `if (type=="dialer")`. That does not work the way you think it does. You have to write `if (type.equals("dialer"))` instead. See the linked issue.

Comment: @Jesper I had read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/16897106). Read 4 number line in first codeblocks. Even I have tried what you said.. It was working what I expected even your method is also working as I expect. So I repeat that's not the case for having current issue.

Comment: Try wrapping your call text views (Name , Contact number and time stamp) in a layout and attach click listener to that layout, instead of this "holder.itemView.setOnClickListener".

Comment: But you are **not** comparing string literals like `"test" == "test"`, you are comparing a variable `type` to a string literal `"dialer"`. So line 4 of the answer you mentioned does not apply.

Comment: @Jesper OK OK! I HAVE USED THAT NOW...